# The best way to check if array has two numbers in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

There is a way to check if array has Numbers:

```
check(var, [Number]);
```

Is there any good way to check if array has certaing number of elements and they are numbers?

```
check(var, [Number, Number]); // Error of template
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of check array of 10 numbers:

```
has10Numbers = Match.Where(function (x) {
  check(x, [Number]);
  return x.length == 10;
});
check(var, has10Numbers);
```

**Update**

Assume that `Number` here means finite number, not NaN, Infinite, you can use this:

```
isFiniteNumeric = Match.Where(function(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
});

has2FiniteNumbers = Match.Where(function (x) {
  check(x, [isFiniteNumeric]);
  return x.length == 2;
});

check([1,2], has2FiniteNumbers); // => true
check([1,NaN], has2FiniteNumbers); // => raise Error
```

Comment: This doesn't work, apparently ```check(x, [Number])``` will pass with array like: ```[19.778696, NaN]```.  I need to be sure that both elements in array are numbers

Comment: Yes, it will pass, because `NaN`, `Infinity` and `-Infinity` is primitive and is `Number`. That works as the document points out at `http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/matchpatterns`. Can you clarify what `Number` in your expectation?